# Image positioning issue

Tags: css, image

I have placed an image on flash player. The following is the code which I have used

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/Technical/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/Technical/js/jquery.pngFix.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(window).load(function () {
            jQuery('.VideoLikeContent').hide();
        });
    });

    function showImage() { jQuery(document).ready(function () { jQuery('.VideoLikeContent').show(); }); }
    function hideImage() { jQuery('#prodimg').hide(); showImage(); }

</script>

<a href="#" onclick="hideImage(); return false;">
    <img id="prodimg" style="position: absolute" 
      height="400px" width="600px" alt="" src="/Technical/images/FINAL-SCREEN-ART.aspx" />
</a>
```

On click on image, the image disappears & the video starts to play.
Note: The image somewhere in the middle

The functionality is working fine.But  when i refresh the page, the image flickers (comes down for a fraction of second & thus exposing the video). How can I fix this?

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: could put your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Is it visible and then disappears and reappears again?  Or just not visible at first then becomes visible?

Comment: Also - rather than using `onclick="..."` you should really bind the events with jQuery `.click()`, seeing as how you are using the framework anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS:

```
.VideoLikeContent {
    display:none;
}
```